# Uso de IF entre columnas Python

Tags: python

Soy nuevo y no entiendo mucho, como puedo llevar a cabo esto, ya que ahora me aparece el error de que el valor verdadero es ambiguo.

```
   if Tienda1['Suma'] > 61000:
        Tienda1['Final'] = 61000
    else:
        Tienda1['Final'] = Tienda1['Suma']
```

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que estás usando Pandas (más que nada por el error que mencionas que te aparece). En ese caso `Tienda1['Suma']` es una columna del dataframe, y cuando haces una comparación como:

```
Tienda1['Suma'] > 61000
```

esta comparación es *vectorial*, es decir, se compara cada uno de los elementos de esa columna con el valor 61000. Cada valor por separado puede ser mayor que 61000 o no, por lo que el resultado de esa comparación es un vector de booleanos, con `True` para los elementos mayores de 61000 y `False` para los que no.

Así pues ¿qué quieres decir con que la columna sea mayor de 61000? ¿Que todos los elementos lo son? ¿Que al menos hay uno que lo es?

Si es lo primero, debes hacer `(Tienda1['Suma'] > 61000).all()` y si es lo segundo debes hacer `(Tienda1['Suma'] > 61000).any()`.

## Actualización

El objetivo del usuario era "limitar" los valores de esa columna a 61000, fijando a este valor cualquiera que fuera mayor.

Para eso pandas admite expresiones booleanas entre corchetes, así: `Tienda1[expresion_booleana]`. Esa expresión debe ser algo que produzca como resultado una columna de `True` o `False`, por ejemplo una comparación como la que antes expliqué, y en base a ella Pandas seleccionará solo las filas en las que dicha expresión tenga valor `True`.

Usando esa técnica, podemos seleccionar aquellas filas en las que haya un valor mayor de 61000, y a ellas asignarles 61000. Esto lo hace la siguiente expresión:

```
Tienda1["Final"] = Tienda1["Suma"]
Tienda1.loc[Tienda1['Final']>61000, 'Final'] = 61000
```

Esto se lee así:

- Primero hacemos una copia de la columna `"Suma"` en otra nueva llamada `"Final"` (si ya existía la columna `"Final"` será sobreescrita).
- Toma el dataframe `Tienda1` y usa `.loc` es para seleccionar ciertas celdas. `.loc` especificará entre corchetes, separado por una coma, las filas y las columnas deseadas. En nuestro caso:

  - Las filas que cumplan la condición `Tienda1['Final']>61000`
  - Y dentro de ellas, la columna `'Final'`
- Asigna a esas celdas el valor 61000
- (las que no han sido seleccionadas quedan como estaban)

### Otra posibilidad

Pandas también tiene el método `df.where(condicion)` que te da los valores del dataframe en cuestión para aquellos elementos que cumplan la condición. Este método admite un segundo valor: `df.where(condicion, si_no)` que será retornado para cada elemento que no cumpla la condición.

Podemos usar eso para hacer una copia de `Tienda1['Suma']`, pero solo *donde* su valor sea menor o igual a 61000, y si es mayor usar `si_no=61000`. Es decir:

```
Tienda1["Final"] = Tienda1["Suma"].where(Tienda1["Suma"]<=61000, 61000)
```

Comment: Lo que quiero es que esta columna llamada suma se mantenga igual, con la unica diferencia de que no existan numeros mayores a 61000 y de haberlos se cambien por este maximo (61000). No estoy seguro si con los IF es el camino correcto.

Comment: @Aferreccio Entiendo, He ampliado la respuesta para explicarte cómo hacer esto, pues Pandas tiene su propia sintaxis